# How to structure MongoDB, Data models and Routes (NodeJS / Express) with multiple data sources

Tags: mongodb, express, data-modeling

My backend app is receiving four data-types each from it's own source (articles, videos, galleries and podcasts). This data should be accessible by client apps ideally as **one** stream that contains all four data-types sorted by publishDate.

Keeping in mind MongoDB's mantra *"Data that is accessed together should be stored together"* I was wondering which option to take:

## Option 1

Store all four data-types as one document — meaning they share one data model and route

## Option 2

Store them as separate documents then create a view of all four — probably with separate models and shared route

Main goal is to maximise efficiency for frontend client apps accessing the API.

I already have the **articles** stream working in PROD.
I have modified articles model to accommodate podcasts.
I was halfway modifying article routes but paused to re-think the steps.